# Confused about the order of execution SQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have this SQL query can anyone help me with the order of execution like which clause is run first and then last:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM recent_grads
       )
  FROM recent_grads
 WHERE ShareWomen > (SELECT AVG(ShareWomen)
                       FROM recent_grads
                    );
```

1. I know the "FROM" clause in line number 5 is run first because it tells our query that the table or dataset we will be using is called "recent_grads".
2. Then I think the "WHERE" clause is run second and in the WHERE clause, the subquery is run first. When the subquery is run then the subquery is replaced by a certain value. Then we have a proper filter statement.
3. I think the third clause that is run is the "SELECT" clauses from the first line and in that clause, the statement " SELECT COUNT()" is run first which returns the number of filtered rows. Then the subquery is run which returns the number of rows in the dataset without filter, so the original amount of rows.

Can someone please let me know if my order of execution is right, I am not sure about the third one when the "SELECT" clause is called, I wanna know if the subquery in the SELECT clause gets executed first or the COUNT() function itself gets executed first.

Comment: LEAD your Query with EXPLAIN and then your query for a list of the sequence of processing determined by the optimizer.  EXPLAIN will also deliver additional columns of information, including ROWS EXAMINED for each step of the processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am saying almost the same as what you say, but I am speaking more generally about the execution of a `SELECT`.)

Without any subqueries, the clauses of a `SELECT` are required to be in the order that they will be looked at.  (And you cannot shuffle the order.)  The exception is that the columns in the `SELECT` are not used until at least after the `FROM`.

A subquery can be "correlated", meaning it references columns in the outer query, or "uncorrelated", as with both of your subqueries.  For "correlated", the subquery must be run repeatedly.

The existence of an "Aggregate" (the first `COUNT(*)`) without a `GROUP BY`, says to "go through the entire table (`FROM`) to tally up the value.

A subquery that is a "constant" (both of your subqueries) will be treated as a separate `SELECT` to be performed before the main `SELECT`.  (It is indeterminate as to which of the 2 comes first -- as it should not matter.)
After that, you have something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       1234
    FROM recent_grads
    WHERE ShareWomen > 25.678;
```

Does that agree with what you are seeing?

Comment: That make's alot of sense, perfectly said!